# thorowing error on else if

Tags: php

I have given 2 option(upload icon/select icon) in form, but when i am checking it with php its throwing error...

**html**

```
<label class="tagslabel">Upload Icon</label>
<input name="uploadicon" type="file" />
<span>or</span>
<ul class="icons clearfix">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" value="123456" name="selecticon"/>
        <label for="selecticon">
            <img src="pics/123456.jpg" alt="123456" width="34" height="34" />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" value="654321" name="selecticon" />
        <label for="selecticon">
            <img src="pics/654321.jpg" alt="654321" width="34" height="34" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**php**

```
if (!empty($_FILES['uploadicon']['name'])) {
     //do image processing and validation
}
else {
    if($_POST['selecticon'] == '') $errors['selecticon'] = 'Please Select An Icon or upload Icon!';
}
```

but its throwing following error, if i upload image instead of selecting one.

```
Notice: Undefined index: selecticon
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
if($_POST['selecticon'] == '')
```

to

```
if (!isset($_POST['selecticon']))
```

Comment: The mistake is that if **$_POST['selecticon']** isn't setted, you can't access it, so you have that notice. isset prevent this type of behaviour by control if the variable "exists"

Comment: personally I favor `if (empty($_POST['selecticon']))` to negating the `isset` because I feel it's more semantically appropriate, but tomato-tomahto i suppose :) +1

Comment: @seoppc Like DonCallisto said, no value is set to the `$_POST['selecticon']` when you do not select any. So you are trying to access an unexisting value.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the user selects neither of your options, nor uploads a file themselves. In which case you should check for the existence of 'selecticon' in the $_POST superglobal. Something like this:

```
 if(!isset($_POST['selecticon'] || $_POST['selecticon'] == '') $errors['selecticon'] = 'Please Select An Icon or upload Icon!'
```